# read gray-scale image without printing its intensity values c++

Tags: c++, opencv, imread

I have searched a lot for this issue but did not find any solution. In my current project, I have to enter the image path as an argument, and that is a sample execution of the program.

[image: sample]

This code always print image **intensity** values which **slows down** program execution, as I work with huge images (the image is a sample for the problem).

`src1= imread(image_name,0);`

I have also tried to use:

`cvtColor(src,src1,COLOR_RGB2GRAY);`

But with the same result. Is there any way to avoid printing these values on screen?

Here is the code sample, worked until i converted it into arguments !!

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Mat img;
string image_name=argv[1];
Mat src1;

 img= imread(image_name,1);

 src1= imread(image_name,0);  // this code causes the program to print out 
                              // image values 

//  cvtColor(src,src1,COLOR_RGB2GRAY); // i have tried using this code 
                                        //instead but got the same result.

if(! img.data )                              // Check for invalid input
{
    std::cerr<<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    system("pause");
    return -1;
}
.....
```

Comment: what code is doing the printing?

Comment: Screenshots are discouraged here.  Are you able to provide more of your code, and the expected inputs/outputs?  The issue is near impossible to solve without code, though I expect it's as simple as commenting out a std::cout statement somewhere.

Comment: Nothing in the shown code prints except std::cerr<<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;` and it does not print the entire image

Comment: i know it is weird problem, i don't know if  there something in the cvtColor build-in that prints the intensity values. This slows down the program execution as i load 512x512 image, and i have to wait until it finishes the print process. Which makes my code much more  slower.

Comment: I would suggest making a minimal example like a simple program that reads an argument and performs `imread`. If it still print intensity values, it might be your OpenCV build.

Comment: that's sounds a good idea, i will do it as soon i went home from work, thanks

Comment: problem solved thanks guys for your help.